# Parallel number systems don't scale well

Tags: parallelization

I'm working on Residue Number System. This is basically a set of relatively coprime integers, let's say $\{3,4,5\}$ and we define its range to be the product of the moduli, i.e. $M=3\cdot4\cdot5=60$. Then we can represent all integers X in $[0,M-1]$ in their RNS format like $$\{X\bmod3,X\bmod 4, X\bmod 5\}$$ and we can add/subtract/multiply them (modulo each modulus) **in parallel** for all moduli channels. For example, if $X=7=\{1,3,2\}$ and $Y=8=\{2,0,3\}$ then

$$X\cdot Y=\{1\cdot 2 \bmod 5, 3\cdot 0 \bmod 5, 2\cdot 3 \bmod 5\}=\{2,0,1\}.$$
Theoretically, as numbers scale up in real applications like cryptography, there might be significant savings, because instead of multiplying 2 let's say 2048-bit numbers, we can use an RNS with just 32-bit channels and multiply as before. I'm trying to visualize this somehow in Mathematica but my results are not consistent. To start with, my system has 2 cores with hyperthreading, thus 4 logical cores in total.

I defined the following "manual" function for multiplication in RNS, where I assume that my RNS has 4 channels assigned to each logical core

```
ParallelExecute[X_List, Y_List, Base_List] := {                         
   ParallelEvaluate[Mod[X[[1]]*Y[[1]], Base[[1]]], Kernels[][[1]]],                             
   ParallelEvaluate[Mod[X[[2]]*Y[[2]], Base[[2]]], Kernels[][[2]]],                     
   ParallelEvaluate[Mod[X[[3]]*Y[[3]], Base[[3]]], Kernels[][[3]]],                                 
   ParallelEvaluate[Mod[X[[4]]*Y[[4]], Base[[4]]], Kernels[][[4]]]
};
```

Then I take a simple example of multiplying 2 2048-bit integers and the equivalent of multiplying in parallel their RNS representation over 1024-bit parallel channels. One would expect a significant improvement but:

```
In[129]:= X*Y // AbsoluteTiming
Out[129]= {7.*10^-6, Huge Number omitted here}
```

and in RNS

```
In[143]:= ParallelExecute[XRNS, YRNS, B] // AbsoluteTiming
Out[143]= {0.004377, RNS result omitted here}
```

I suspect that typical arithmetic operations use the underlying hyperthreading or inherent parallel techniques in Mathematica but I would expect that same thing would happen for RNS but seems not.

What would be an approach that would reveal the speedups in RNS? Perhaps translate operations to bitwise operations? Any advice on manipulating the parallelism techniques offered in Mathematica?

Comment: Your `ParallelExecute` function evaluates something on kernel 1, waits until it's done, then evaluates something on kernel 2, waits until it's done, and so on. You are slowing down your computation, not speeding it up.  Use `Parallelize[{eval1, eval2, ...}]`. Or use `ParallelSubmit` (look it up) for asynchronous evaluations.

Comment: Even if you fix this, such fine-grained parallelization is not helpful in Mathematica.  The parallelization overhead is high in Mathematica, and inter-kernel communication is slow.  Parallelization makes sense only if each individual evaluation takes sufficiently long. I wouldn't bother at all with sub-second evaluation times, though I do not know where the exact limit is (I'm sure it's lower than a second, but it strongly depends on how much data you need to send to subkernels).

Comment: @Szabolcs This is correct, the point is to use this representation in a series of intensive computations to speed them up.

Comment: @Szabolcs Regarding your comment on `ParallelSubmit` , it does perform faster but it doesn't account for executing the expression right? It only corresponds to submitting the data for evaluation, correct? In that case, if I add the `AbsoluteTiming` for `ParallelSubmit` plus the time for one of the parallel expressions, will I get a realistic estimate?

Comment: The usage is described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/Overview.html), more specifically [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/ConcurrencyManagingParallelProcesses.html#11891747). You would need to measure everything, including `ParallelSubmit` and `WaitAll`, to get the full timing.  In case youare not aware: Keep using `AbsouteTiming`, as you have been doing so far. Do not use `Timing`, as it doesn't measure time spent by parallel kernels.

Comment: There are other things to pay attention to as well, to increase performance, but I do not fully understand what you are doing (and how long you expect a single submitted evaluation to take), so it's hard to comment ... another problem of your ParallelExecute is that it copies whole data structures over to each subkernel, not just the parts that are being used. E.g. `Base` is copied over fully, then `Base[[1]]` is evaluated on the subkernel. It *may* be faster to only copy `Base[[1]]`

Comment: In general, what is the command that allows you to submit independent operations to the kernels, i.e. Kernel1 does Op1, Kernel2 does Op2, etc..?

Comment: Do you mean that you want something that is asynchronous like ParallelSubmit and lets you select a specific kernel, like ParallelEvaluate?  I do not think it is possible. If it is, it must be the (undocumented) `Scheduling` option of `ParallelSubmit`. I do not know what it does.  Otherwise, you would have to read the source code of the parallel tools and find the appropriate internal functions to use.  Doing that is a bad idea in most cases.  Why do you want to control which kernel to evaluate stuff on?